# Simple Calculator cant get past println

Tags: java

So here's my code.

https://ideone.com/ok42QZ

```
    System.out.println("setcaculatorinput");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int z = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("setvalueA");
    int a = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("setvalueB");
```

The main problem is that I cant get past System.out.println("setcaculatorinput") as it crashes right after that line.

Comment: *It crashes*, what exception does it give and what is the stacktrace?

Comment: If only there was such a stacktrace that would tell you exactly what the problem is..

Comment: take a closer look at `if (condition);`

Comment: It should be on the link I posted

Comment: @Pshemo Although that will create a later problem, the current problem is that `+` cannot be parsed as an integer.

Comment: You expect the first input to be the operation. It probably won't be an int, right? Also your ```if``` statements won't do nothing because you have empty statement after them. And last thing is that you probably shouldn't calculate values which you're not going to use(c,d,e,f)

Comment: Um, could you reword that. Sorry -3-

Comment: @JoshM Agree, that is why I didn't post it as answer but comment. It is not solution, it is advice.

Comment: @Pshemo Fair enough. : )

Comment: do it like this : `int z=Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());` . you have endline character at the end of that entry from console, which is not an int, hence there is a mismatch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me format your code...
first:

```
if ("+".equals(z))
    ; // it's an empty condition!

{ // this is an init block
 System.out.println(c);
}
```

All your code "formated":

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        System.out.println("setcaculatorinput");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int z = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("setvalueA");
        int a = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("setvalueB");
        int b = sc.nextInt();
        int c, d, e, f;

        c = (a + b);
        d = (a - b);
        e = (a * b);
        f = (a / b);

        if ("+".equals(z))
            ;
        if ("-".equals(z))
            ;
        if ("*".equals(z))
            ;
        if ("/".equals(z))
            ;

        { // init block
            System.out.println(c);
            System.out.println(d);
            System.out.println(e);
            System.out.println(f);
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }
```

The error is shown because you try to read an non integer character, read the Javadoc of `new Scanner("").nextInt();` and you'll see that it throws: "InputMismatchException - if the next token does not match the Integer regular expression, or is out of range".

I give you a short solution, but I don't recommend it since no checks are performed on the inputs..

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("setcaculatorinput");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int result = 0;

        System.out.println("setvalueA=");
        int a = sc.nextInt();

        System.out.println("setOperator=");
        String op = sc.next();

        System.out.println("setvalueB=");
        int b = sc.nextInt();

        if ("+".equals(op))
            result = a + b;
        else if ("-".equals(op))
            result = a - b;
        else if ("*".equals(op))
            result = a * b;
        else if ("/".equals(op))
            result = a / b;

        System.out.println("The result is=" + result);
        System.exit(0);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with trying to parse the input `+` as an integer in line 13 of your code (along with your first input on stdin). You can switch the call from `.nextInt()` to `.nextLine()` and change the type of `z` to a `String`

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    System.out.println("setcaculatorinput");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    //switch z out for a String instead of an int, and use .nextLine()
    String z = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("setvalueA");
    int a = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("setvalueB");
    int b = sc.nextInt();
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) for starter change your line 17 to `String z = sc.next();`
you are reading integer, passing character, and further treat it as string

2) after your each if statement, you have `;` so each block after will be executed anyway

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println("setcaculatorinput");
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int z = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());   
System.out.println("setvalueA");
int a = Integer.parseInt( sc.nextLine());
System.out.println("setvalueB");
```

Basically what is happenning is , While you are reading double as sc.nextInt(), you are reading only the int, however there would be ENDLINE character when you hit enter on the stream that is not read by sc.nextInt().

Answer (score 0):

This code will work :

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        System.out.println("setcaculatorinput");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String z = sc.next();
        System.out.println("setvalueA");
        int a = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("setvalueB");
        int b = sc.nextInt();
        int c;
        int d;
        int e;
        int f;
        c = ( a + b );
        d = ( a - b );
        e = ( a * b );
        f = ( a / b );
        if("+".equals(z))
        {
        System.out.println(c);
        }
        if("-".equals(z))
        {
        System.out.println(d);
        }
        if("*".equals(z))
        {
        System.out.println(e);
        }
        if("/".equals(z))
        {
        System.out.println(f);
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Thank you